# What does the N in varchar(N) refer to

Tags: sql-server, database

What does the N in varchar(N) refer to when describing a field in a database. Is it the number of characters or bytes. Also, one is using UTF-8, a character may use more than one byte.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the maximum number of characters.

`nvarchar(1000)` = max 1000 unicode chars.

Answer (score 3):

`varchar` cannot hold Unicode characters, so `n` in `varchar(n)` means both number of characters and number of bytes. In case of `nvarchar(n)` the `n` means the number of Unicode characters, with storage size of two times `n` bytes.

If you query `information_schema.columns`, there will be, among others, two columns of particular interest: `CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH` and `CHARACTER_OCTET_LENGTH`. The former holds the number of characters, and the latter contains the number of bytes.

Comment: It is NOT the number of characters, but the number of byte pairs. See "misconception" in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/nchar-and-nvarchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Answer (score 1):

1. nr of characters

Answer (score 0):

It is neither! For nchar/nvarchar it is the number of byte pairs (hence characters encoded as surrogate byte pairs use two, in UTF-16).

Since many many years have passed since this question was answered incorrecly the assertion made in the question that varchar is single-byte encoding only has also become false. It is possible to have UTF-8-encoded varchar columns, and varchar(n) specifies the number of bytes, not the number of characters (UTF-8 encoding requiring up to 4 bytes for a character).

[Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/char-and-varchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)