# In mysql if I have a column (name VARCHAR(5)) and I am inserting a string with more than 5 characters it is working. But how?

Tags: mysql

I am confused what does 'n' specify in `varchar(n)`? I have a column (`name VARCHAR(5)`). This means that this can hold up to 5 characters. But when I am inserting a string with more than 5 characters, it is working fine.

So my question is what does this 'n' really mean?

Can anyone please explain this to me clearly?

Thanks :)

Comment: Does this answer your question?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/755598/what-does-the-n-in-varcharn-refer-to

Comment: What does "*working fine*" actually mean?  No errors or your table gets populated with more characters than specified length?  Did you do `SELECT` after your `INSERT`?

Comment: Not in my book. Just tried in MySQL 8.x and errors out with: `Data Truncation error occurred on a write  of column 0Data was 0 bytes long and 0 bytes were transferred.` -- No insertion takes place.

Comment: typically MySQL will issue a *warning* or *error* when values are truncated; settings of sql_mode will affect the behavior. I suspect MySQL is issuing a warning, and whatever client you are executing the SQL from is ignoring the warning.  the mysql command line client will automatically show the warnings if it's started with the (default) --show-warnings option

Comment: @Ben no It doesn't answer my question

Comment: @TheImpaler Yes it is inserting into the database without any issue.

Comment: Must a special SQL_MODE on your specific database.

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL, with datatype `VARCHAR(n)`, the `n` specifies the maximum number of characters that can be stored. That's what it really means.

As far as the behavior you are observing, MySQL will typically issue either a *warning* or *error* when assigned values are truncated.  The behavior is informed by settings of `sql_mode`, for example, if we attempt an operation that results in truncation of a VARCHAR value in an InnoDB table, and `sql_mode` setting for the session includes `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES`, MySQL will terminate the statement, and throw an error.

If `sql_mode` is more relaxed, then the statement is allowed to proceed, a truncated value is stored, and a *warning* is issued.

The client can issue a `SHOW WARNINGS` immediately following the operation to retrieve the warning messages.

Some clients automatically do this, for example, mysql command line client started with default `--show-warnings` option

---

**FOLLOWUP**

Another possible explanation for the observed behavior, if the column is actually defined as `VARCHAR(5)`, and it appears that more than five characters are being stored, and more than five characters are being returned ...

It could be the code is profoundly broken in the way character set encodings are being handled, broken in a way that no developer worth his salt should be tripped up by in the year 2020.

Possibly:

- the column is defined with a multibyte characterset e.g. `utf16`
- the value being sent by the client is a different encoding (single byte like `latin1`)
- the client misinforms the server what characterset the client is using, telling MySQL that its sending `utf16` so MySQL doesn't perform any characterset translation
- the sequence of bytes is stored in the column (in this example, no more than 10 bytes)
- when the value is retrieved, its a sequence of bytes that MySQL server thinks is five or fewer `utf16` characters
- the mysql client also thinks its `utf16` encoding, but the application does the wrong thing and looks at it like it's `latin1`

Or, more briefly, the program is doing precisely the wrong thing when it mishandles character set encodings.

https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/

Comment: Do you know how to check my sql_mode ?

Comment: **`SELECT @@sql_mode`**  will return current value of the session variable, which is inherited from the global setting when the session starts. the value for the session can be modified with a SET statement, e.g. `SET @@sql_mode = 'NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION' `   see  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html

Comment: Thanks for helping me out.